# Can a group have a child relationship to two or more different parent groups?

Tags: groups

Assuming that I have the groups GR1, GR2, GR3, GR4, etc and parent groups PG-A and PG-B;

can GR1 be configured to be a child group both in parent group PG-A and simultaneously be a child group in parent group PG-B?

I could not find an answer in the CiviCRM documentation.

Answer (score 2):

After some thought and experimentation, I discovered that any group can be in more than one parent group.